# Windows Cluster An error was encountered while determining shared storage

Tags: storage, cluster, failovercluster, rpc

Our SAN manager has added a new disk for our cluster. this is a new 6TB disk that will be used for backup and will be part of a file share. I have put the disk online, initialized it and assigned the letter V.
The disk is now online on 1 node with the letter V. when I want to add the disk to the cluster, I have the 'Operation has failed.' notification.

when I use the Powershell to see the disks:

```
Get-ClusterAvailableDisk
```

results in:

```
Get-ClusterAvailableDisk : An error was encountered while determining shared storage for '99-001-003-S120'.
    A remote procedure call (RPC) protocol error occurred.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ClusterAvailableDisk -Cluster 99-001-003-s120
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ClusterAvailableDisk], ClusterCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Get-ClusterAvailableDisk,Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.GetClusterAvailableDiskCommand
```

when I use the GUI to add the disk, it results in the same error message and the 'A remote procedure call (RPC) protocol error occurred.'

I have added before disks to the same cluster and that worked fine.
I have checked that the service is running (RPC), and that is the case.

Comment: What do your EventLogs say? Is the disk visible on both nodes? What state is the disk in on both nodes?

Comment: The only notification I can find is:

`WMI Notification:
The root\mscluster namespace is marked with the RequiresEncryption flag. Access to this namespace might be denied if the script or application does not have the appropriate authentication level. Change the authentication level to Pkt_Privacy and run the script or application again.
`

In the cluster log is the same message
`An error was encountered while determining shared storage.`

The disk is only visible by 4/8 of nodes. We have 4 on each DC Site. This is the same as our other backup disk.

Comment: Is the `WMI notication` generated at the same time when you're trying to add the disk, or is showing up at regular intervals? Have you tried adding it to the cluster from another node? Are you performing the task as an administrator?

Comment: The notification is at regular intervals. I'm logged in as an administrator. Before it always worked when I right click on disks and choose add disk. I will ask our SAN manager to set another server as primary owner.

Comment: stack trace from the eventvwr in diagnostic channel:
`The action 'Add Disk' did not complete. - System.ApplicationException: An error was encountered while determining shared storage for '99-001-003-S120'. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: A remote procedure call (RPC) protocol error occurred.`
EventId 4612

Comment: The `WMI notification` might be caused by a monitoring system, I've seen similar events caused by our monitoring software which was trying to poll some cluster state data from the node. With regards to the RPC errors, sounds to me like there's something else going on here. Do you have any other management issues on this cluster?

Comment: The rest seems to function properly. I have been looking and testing, that was, is possible of course for production. I find it very strange since, for the rest nothing changed to the cluster, no added roles, no added nodes,... I have added a disk a month ago the same way with no problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I can be of much help then. If you have support, maybe calling Microsoft would be the best bet.

Comment: yes I have logged a case at Microsoft now, will update this thread with the outcome so it can be of use to someone else if needed. I hoped it would be something simple. By this way I want to thank you also for your time!